# Range filter not working for "gt" operator but working for "lt"

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, kibana

I am using elastic search to index my documents and wanted to filter documents based on a specific property. Here is my code:

```
filter.push({
            range: {"audience.ethnicity.asian" : { gt: 50 } }
        })
```

It doesn't work with gt operator (sends back results that are not consistent) but works with lt operator

```
filter.push({
                range: {"audience.ethnicity.asian" : { lt: 50 } }
            })
```

This works surprisingly. I have double checked that the property value IS an integer. I have tried many different ways but can't seem to figure out what am I missing. 
Mapping:

```
  "audience": {
    "properties": {
      "age": {
        "properties": {
          "13-17": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "18-24": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "25-34": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "35-44": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "45-64": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "eighteen": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "fortyfive": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "thirteen": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "thirtyfive": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "twentyfive": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      },
      "ages": {
        "properties": {
          "13-17": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "18-24": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "25-34": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "35-44": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "45-64": {
            "type": "float"
          }
        }
      },
      "ethnicity": {
        "properties": {
          "African American": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "Asian": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "Hispanic": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "White / Caucasian": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "african": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "asian": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "hispanic": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "white": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "gender": {
        "properties": {
          "female": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "male": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "genders": {
        "properties": {
          "FEMALE": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "MALE": {
            "type": "float"
          }
        }
      },
      "gendersPerAge": {
        "properties": {
          "13-17": {
            "properties": {
              "FEMALE": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "MALE": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "18-24": {
            "properties": {
              "FEMALE": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "MALE": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "25-34": {
            "properties": {
              "FEMALE": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "MALE": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "35-44": {
            "properties": {
              "FEMALE": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "MALE": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "45-64": {
            "properties": {
              "FEMALE": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "MALE": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }          "audience": {
    "properties": {
      "age": {
        "properties": {
          "13-17": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "18-24": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "25-34": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "35-44": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "45-64": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "eighteen": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "fortyfive": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "thirteen": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "thirtyfive": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "twentyfive": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      },
      "ages": {
        "properties": {
          "13-17": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "18-24": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "25-34": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "35-44": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "45-64": {
            "type": "float"
          }
        }
      },
      "ethnicity": {
        "properties": {
          "African American": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "Asian": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "Hispanic": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "White / Caucasian": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "african": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "asian": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "hispanic": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "white": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "gender": {
        "properties": {
          "female": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "male": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "genders": {
        "properties": {
          "FEMALE": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "MALE": {
            "type": "float"
          }
        }
      },
      "gendersPerAge": {
        "properties": {
          "13-17": {
            "properties": {
              "FEMALE": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "MALE": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "18-24": {
            "properties": {
              "FEMALE": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "MALE": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "25-34": {
            "properties": {
              "FEMALE": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "MALE": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "35-44": {
            "properties": {
              "FEMALE": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "MALE": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "45-64": {
            "properties": {
              "FEMALE": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "MALE": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm interested to see your real mapping, i.e. the one you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`. Please share

Comment: @Val - I have limited knowledge of elastic search. DO you mean the query I run on Kibana?

Comment: In Kibana / Dev Tools, you can run this: `GET your_index` (replace `your_index` by the real index name)

Comment: Done. But the result a huge object. Which specific part/property do you need?

Comment: @Val updated the original question with mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mapping, the `audience.ethnicity.asian` field is of type text, hence the range query is doing a **lexical range comparison** instead of a **numerical range comparison**.

Numerically, 123 > 50, but lexically 123 < 50 because ASCII character 1 comes before 5, that's exactly the issue you're suffering from here.

I'm not sure if you can use the `audience.ethnicity.Asian` field, which is a float. If not, you'll need to change the mapping of `audience.ethnicity.asian` to a numeric type (`integer`, `float`, etc) and reindex your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Is there an easy way I can change the mapping?

Comment: You cannot change the mapping, you need to create a new index with the proper mapping and reindex your data into that new index.

Comment: Yes. Totally works. Reindexed with correct mappings. Thanks. Sorry, been sick past few days and couldn't mark your answer as correct.