# ElasticSearch Range query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created the index by using the following mapping:

```
put test1
{
    "mappings": {
        "type1": {
            "properties": {
                "age": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 32766
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Added following documents into index:

```
PUT test1/type1/1/_create
{
  "age":50
}

PUT test1/type1/2/_create
{
  "age":100
}

PUT test1/type1/3/_create
{
  "age":150
}

PUT test1/type1/4/_create
{
  "age":200
}
```

I have used the following range query to fetch result:

```
GET test1/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "age" : {
                "lte" : 150
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is giving me the following response :

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test1",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "age": 100
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test1",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "age": 150
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the above response not showing document having age is 50 it is showing only age is 100 and 150. As 50 also less than 200. What is wrong here?
Can anyone help me to get a valid result?
In my schema age field type text, I don't want to change it.

How can I get a valid result?

Comment: What is your ES version? Almost certain that this can be achieved using [Scripted queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html)

Comment: I am using ES 6.3.2

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50825828/range-filter-not-working-for-gt-operator-but-working-for-lt/50849101#50849101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Tested on local system and it is working.

**NOTE:** Ideally, you would want the mappings to be correct, but if there is no other choice and you are not the person to decide on the mapping then you can still achieve it by following.

For ES version 6.3 onwards, try this.

```
 GET test1/type1/_search
    {
        "query": {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "script" : {
                            "source": "Integer.parseInt(doc['age.raw'].value) <= 150",
                            "lang": "painless"
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Sources to refer:**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-script-query.html

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/painscript-script-cast-string-as-int/97034

Comment: Please confirm if it works or tell what went wrong. I will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the response I have tried above query but getting following error:


"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [age] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."

Comment: Try now. It might be because the query used text instead of keyword.

Comment: So I made change by using `doc['age.raw']` instead of `doc['age']`.

Comment: @SurajDalvi Hi did you get a chance to try this solution? If it works for you please accept the solution or provide details for what went wrong.

Comment: yes, it is working now. How We can use same this for date field is any way find date greater than some date using the above script?

Comment: @SurajDalvi Glad it worked, kindly please accept the answer if it helped. For date fields if they are mapped correctly you can simply use `range`. Have a look here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: date fields not mapped properly they mapped as above (type text) so how I can use above query for date fields?

Comment: @SurajDalvi Refer this for how to convert string to date: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/converting-a-string-date-to-a-date-field-using-scripted-fields-in-kibana/108952/4  ... If you need any further clarification please ask a new question. .

Comment: can we add try catch in above query if age field is blank then it is "null" then it is giving null_pointer_exception so how we can handle it?

Comment: yes you can do it in the script. Instead of directly typecasting to integer first check if `doc` contains key `age`. If it doesn't contain you can return a very high integer value. `(doc.containsKey('age')?Integer.parseInt(doc['age.raw'].value) : 100000) <= 150`

Comment: Please accept the answer since it looks like it is helping you. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Because age field type is text, the range query is using alphabetically order.  So the results are correct:

- "100"<"150"
- "150"="150"
- "50">"150"

If you are ingesting only numbers in `age` field, you should change the `age` field type to `number`, or add another inner field as number, just you did with `raw` inner field.

Comment: I have created the index with the inner field with number type:

`put test1 {
 "mappings": {
  "type1": {
   "properties": {
    "age": {
     "type": "text",
     "fields": {
      "raw": {
       "type": "keyword",
       "ignore_above": 32766
      },
      "raw1": {
       "type": "integer"
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}`

And then I have added the following document into it:
`PUT test1/type1/3/_create
{
  "age":"test"
}`
It gives me the following error:
`"type": "number_format_exception",
      "reason": "For input string: \"test\"`
help me into this?

Comment: As I already told you,  you can only add another inner_field as `number`, only if you are ingesting numbers, not text.

Comment: How we can use the above query with the array for example:

Comment: How we can use the above query with the array for example:
PUT test1/type1/4/_create
{
  "age":[200,100,500,400]
}

Please let me know how we can use the above query with the array?

Comment: @SurajDalvi The array is treated in elasticsearch like an ordinary variable. There are no differences between documents: {"age":10} and {"age":[10,100]}. Actually you can ingest those 2 documents and you will see that both are ingested. The only requirement  is that all the array values must have the same type (all ints or all strings etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Type for your field age in mapping is set to text. That is reason it is doing dictionary sorting where 50 > 150. Please use long data type. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html